# c search string if type character, int type, operator type

Tags: c++, numbers

So what I have going on is a character array such as "hello world! 32 is 32time..." I need to check each position and determine whether it is of type char int or operator. I know I can do this with switch statements and create a function that outputs a number based on the type. However I was wondering if there was a much more clever way to do this, ultimately saving space and time.

I also know of the  strchr(array, character), but again this just seems tedious. Is there already a function that i can use that would output whether a character is of int char or oper, or even perhaps a checking for many different characters at once ex. checkType(array, "abcdefgh....")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the functions isalnum, isalpha, isascii, isblank, iscntrl, isdigit, isgraph, islower, isprint, ispunct, isspace, isupper, isxdigit?

Comment: Yes exactly that, sorry I had to post here, I guess I need to refine my google searches a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
char *str = "hello world! 32 is 32time"
char *c = str;

while(*c) {
  if (isalpha(*c)) {
    /* do something */
  }
  else if (isdigit(*c)) {
    /* do something */
  }
  else if (ispunct(*c)) {
    /* do something */
  }
  else {
    /* do something else */
  }

  c++;
}
```

Note that this assumes you're dealing with a null terminated string to exit the `while` loop.